# Source for wind energy potential for India in GIS format

Tags: data, climate, india

I am looking for wind energy data (they can be wind speed at any height or wind energy potential) for India in a GIS format.

Like the data displayed the link below: 
http://www.arcgis.com/apps/OnePane/basicviewer/index.html?appid=f03b21b359964374a1d4c274de254f26

Answer (score 2):

Oddly enough, I had a chat last night with a fellow from the National Renewable Energy Lab (NREL) here in Denver. He said they are doing work in India on wind / renewables but the Indian Gov't will not release the data they need for their work!

Just thought I'd share that since I saw this post and had this discussion last night...

Answer (score 2):

The [Global Wind Atlas](https://globalwindatlas.info/) by DTU Energy and the World Bank Group is definitely worth checking out. It contains GIS data on wind speed, capacity factor and direction (and much more) at 50, 100 and 200m hub height, with a 250x250m resolution, free of charge.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an online, data download link, but I know that the 'Center for Wind Energy technology' had released am 'Indian Wind Atlas' in 2010, which is the most comprehensive (IMHO) report on this issue.

Most of the Google hits that you see for this term, are actually using data and maps from this report.

You might be able to access this Atlas from some Library.

Answer (score -1):

National Institute of Wind Enery (NIWE) formerly C-WET has the wind resource data for pan India
http://niwe.res.in/